# Battery Terrible on Ubuntu 16 with Asus Laptop

Tags: nvidia, power-management, battery

My battery performance is terrible on my Asus N751JK laptop. I get around 4 hours in Windows and (max!) 1.5 hours in Ubuntu.

The thing is, before upgrading to Ubuntu 16, I had around 3 hours in Ubuntu, mostly when I used a CPU Frequency Scaling indicator (indicator-cpufreq) at the lowest level. With Ubuntu 16, I only have two options here: Performance and Powersave. Previously I had many more and I think that really made the difference.

I've installed powertop, tlp, bumblebee, pm-powersave, and nothing seems to help. I don't use my nvidia video card to save battery as well. I don't really know how to monitor well and understand if things are making positive changes aside from looking at my time remaining on the battery indicator. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I would check `top` to see if there is a process taking a lot of cpu and lower the screen brightness to save battery.